# Draw partial circle as progress bar in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-progressbar

SUMMARY :

Use picture 1 for reference.

I need to keep the grey part under the green part, so that when green decreases, grey becomes visible. But I also want the uncovered part (just grey to not be there). Resulting in a 2/3rd overlapping circle.

---

I am trying to create 2/3rd circle (with rounded corners) as a progress bar in android studio. I am not able to do it.
I was hoping to get your help.

**Current circle:** (PICTURE 1)

[image]

**Circle I need :**

[image]

Shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5" android:useLevel="false"
            android:thicknessRatio="12">
            <solid android:color="#DDD"/>
     </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5" android:useLevel="true"
            android:thicknessRatio="12">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/timerProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        android:indeterminateOnly="false"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle"
        android:rotation="-90"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineBottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineTop"
        android:progress="10"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineBottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

 
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to draw a bar on your own, you can use https://github.com/futuredapp/donut. It is highly customizable so you can achieve the requested behavior easily.

[image: donuts_preview]

Comment: I want to create my own. Do you know how it can be done ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `CircularProgressIndicator` provided by the Material Components library.

Something like:

```
        <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            app:growMode="bidirectional"
            app:trackThickness="8dp"
            app:indicatorColor="@color/green"
            app:trackColor="@color/grey"
            app:indicatorSize="100dp"
            app:trackCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:progress="75"
            android:rotation="225"
            .../>
```

Use these attributes:

- **`trackColor`** you can change the color of the grey/uncovered part. Use the parent background color to hide it.
- **`trackCornerRadius`** to change the rounded corners of the indicator.

You have to apply a rotation depending by the progress value.

```
progress.rotation = 180+((1-value/100)/2*360)
```

[image]
[image]

**Note:** it requires at least the version **`1.3.0-alpha04`**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace from #DDD color to transparent and can put your text above it, It will give you the same design that you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5" android:useLevel="false"
            android:thicknessRatio="12">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5" android:useLevel="true"
            android:thicknessRatio="12">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: This doesnt work. I want grey under the red part. I want 2/3rd circle (like Red) and I also want the underneath to be grey.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve your problem by using Lottie. There are multiple LottieFiles available or you can use your own SVG and load them using Lottie in your app.

> For example. If you use this one
> https://assets9.lottiefiles.com/datafiles/cOSizCzzp3gv6Qv/data.json,
> You can set the view dimensions to show 2/3rd of the circle and you
> can set the duration of your animation.  You can also set start frame
> and end frame of animation.

There are multiple customization options available. You can find more lottie files here: https://lottiefiles.com/
and the implementation here: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android

Hope this helps, good luck!